# Find coordinates of text on a page - c++, windows, VS2013

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, web

Is there any way to retrieve the **coordinates** of input text on the screen *(not on the API itself)*?

*Example in pseudo code:*

```
user types: "example"
```

> example found at [400,355] //on my screen

I have no problem checking if the input is on the screen but I have no idea how to capture the coordinates without OCR which I don't want to have to do.

My question is about **webpages** in particular but I would also be interested in how to do it in general (notepad text, messenger text...).

Ideas appreciated 
Thanks!!!

Comment: This sounds a lot like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/205381). What are you **really** trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery has an .position() function; however, note that the position is relative to the object's parent, and is not the absolute screen position. Though, with a bit of math you can find it.

https://api.jquery.com/position/

Answer (score -1):

in C++ : 
Hope this could work, use this in your handler for [`WM_LBUTTONDOWN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645607%28VS.85%29.aspx):

```
xPos = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam); 
yPos = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
```

..................................................

As said by @user2759788 
jQuery/javascript both can be used for finding coordinates on a webpage.

Comment: Why do you assume that the mouse was pressed? Or that a mouse is even present in the system?